# WPF Representing Tab Items As UserControls - Sharing Data

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I have a WPF application with a large number of tab items containing mainly buttons and text controls. To reduce the size of the XAML file, I would like to represent the tab contents with user controls. The control actions caused by button clicks access the same data, so I'd like to know how to share the data between these user controls.

To illustrate further, my application is controlling a device and the tabs perform various actions depending on various modes of operation. e.g. tab1 has buttons initialise and run, which call myDevice.initialise() and myDevice.run(). Tab2 deals with calibration, therefore calls myDevice.calibrate() etc.

Currently I have the myDevice object created in the main application so would like to know how to share this with custom controls defined for each tab so that the button click callbacks have access to myDevice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to either create a `DependencyProperty` on your `UserControl` so you can pass it `myDevice`, or use a `RelativeSource` binding to set the `DataContext` to `myDevice` for all tab items.

Which you choose depends on how your data layer is organized and what other data you need in your `UserControls`

Here's a quick example of how you could set your `myDevice` property to the TabItem's `DataContext`

```
<TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="DataContext" 
                Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyDevice, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource {x:Type TabControl}}}" />
    </Style>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Im afraid I need to read up a little on RelativeSources and data binding as Im fairly new to WPF.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to keep `List<IOperationMode> OperationsModes` list in `myDevide` and then create set of classes for each operation mode:

```
class OperationModeInitialise : IOperationMode
{
}

class OperationModeCalibrate : IOperationMode
{
}

....
```

and for each type you create `DataTemplate` resource in `TabControl.Resources`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:OperationModeInitialise}">
   <my:OperationModeInitialiseControl/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type OperationModeCalibrate}">
   <my:OperationModeCalibrateControl/>
</DataTemplate>

....
```

bind `myDevice.OperationsModes` to `TabControl.ItemsSource` and you have one tab for each operation mode that share one device.

Comment: This would be my suggestion too if you needed to access data or functionality other than that contained in `myDevice`

Answer (score 0):

You could put a reference to myDevice in your App.vb/App.cs file and make it a public property.. Kind of a hackish way to do it but should work.